# Proper group ownership & permissions to the Laravel app/storage folder on vagrant?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, laravel, laravel-4

I have successfully set up a Vagrant environment to put my laravel application with all its dependencies, as well as configuring the web server as required. I set this up using ubuntu.

The problem that I have is the app/storage folder. I noticed that the first time I loaded the site, it gave me an error with permissions. I then ran a:

```
chmod -R a+rwx app/storage
```

... And that made me load my file properly. When I refreshed, I got a blank screen.

I ran chmod once again, and I had access to my mainpage once again.

I tested my routes only to come with the problem that my application randomly crashed. Running chmod yet again solved this.

I came to the conclusion that my problem is related with group ownership and not so much permissions themselves, because files are being created constantly on the app/storage folder and they are not being created with permissions.

How can I add write permissions to the app/storage folder so everytime new files are made, will have the permissions I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting your config.vm.synced_folder as following in the Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/local/folder", "/vagrant/folder", :owner => 'vagrant', :group =>'www-data', :mount_options => ['dmode=775,fmode=775']
```

Comment: Specifically for the storage folder? Or my overall storage folder? I am confused about the local and vagrant folders here. Do you mean something like this? "  config.vm.synced_folder "src/app/storage", "/vagrant/app/storage", :owner => 'vagrant', :group =>'www-data', :mount_options => ['dmode=775,fmode=775']" ... When I do a git pull, I can do it from any folder pretty much. Does local have to be an absolute path like you illustrated?

Comment: I tried that and whilst I can mount the folder properly, I still have this issue

Comment: I have this line 1:1 with no changes and so it was working for me, maybe I'll be able to find some more ways of doing this.

Answer (score -4):

You must run chmod -R 755.

Hope this helps.
Bye.

Comment: I tried this. If you read my question properly, you can see that I am essentially running this command over and over again. Running chmod works, but once I start browsing and calling the routes, more files are created.